# Quartz Scheduler : Log output of separate jobs to different log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler

Suppose i have 2 jobs scheduled with Quartz-Scheduler

- Job1
- Job2

As of now the log output of both the jobs is dumped in the same log file. I want to log the output of these 2 jobs to two different files

- logfile-job1.txt
- logfile-job2.txt

So effectively at the end of the day, i want to have 3 different log files

1. Quartz-Scheduler ( Main Thread log file, separate )
2. jogfile-job1.txt ( separate log file )
3. jogfile-job2.txt ( separate log file )

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If switching to [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) is an option, all you need is built-in: [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) and [sifting appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender). First add this try-finally clause to your every job (you can use job listeners to avoid repetition):

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    MDC.put("jobId", "job1");
    try {
        //do all the work here
    } finally {
        MDC.remove("jobId");
    }
}
```

It's important to put all the code inside `try`, not before or after. Once your jobs are prepared put this in `logback.xml`:

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
      <key>jobId</key>
      <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
      <appender name="FILE-${jobId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logfile-${jobId}.log</file>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
      </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

It will "just work".

Comment: It's not standard solution. Very Interesting

Answer (score 0):

You can have two log4j property files and configure like this

```
public class Job1 {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Job1.class);
    Job1() {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        log.info("Job1 initilized");
    }
}

public class Job2 {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Job2.class);
    Job2() {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j1.properties");
        log.info("Job2 initilized");
    }
}
```

In log4j.properties specify `log4j.appender.R.File=logfile-job1.log` and log4j1.properties specify `log4j.appender.R.File=logfile-job2.log` Thats it.

Comment: hey vls4j, thanks for the solution. i had tried the similar approach earlier. It didn't work out. The reason being the jobs are not separate classes, but invoked as different instances of Same Class. I will keep you updated. btw Thanx Again :)

Comment: You can log with same log file. when process log file you can filter with name.